# Unable to get react router to switch to another page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I cannot seem to get the react router to work as expected.
I stripped down my code to the following most basic example. When running this it makes no difference if i click on `Home` or `Test` and the router always shows the `Home` page.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Link key="/" to="/">Home</Link>
        <br />
        <Link key="/test" to="/test">Test</Link>
        <Switch>
            <Route key="/" path="/" component={HomePage} />
            <Route key="/test" path="/test" component={TestPage} />
        </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.querySelector('#root'),
);

function HomePage() {
    console.log('HomePage');
    return <h1>Home page</h1>;
}

function TestPage() {
    console.log('TestPage');
    return <h1>Test page</h1>;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `exact` prop to your home route.

```
<Route key="/" path="/" component={HomePage} exact />
```

Edit:

If for any reason you don't want to add the `exact` prop, you can also declare the home route last.